# removing duplicates from a column of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, duplicates

I have a series with a key column that has dates (DateTime Index) in chronological order, and a value column that has arrays. I would like to preserve order and delete individual elements in each row array that appear in a previous row array.

Data:

```
Created
2015-02-08    [X, Y, Z, A]
2015-02-15    [A, B]
2015-02-22    [nan]
2015-03-01    [C]
2015-03-08    [W, F, X, A]
2015-03-15    [Q]
```

From this, I would like to get:

```
Created
2015-02-08    [X, Y, Z, A]
2015-02-15    [B]
2015-02-22    [nan]
2015-03-01    [C]
2015-03-08    [W, F]
2015-03-15    [Q]
```

Comment: Can you add sample (5-6 rows) and desired output of sample?

Comment: Edited my question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to maintain a common list. For each element in a row, check if it is already there in the common list, it not add it to both the common list and output of that particular row, otherwise just ignore it.

Comment: Both great answers. Used the other solution but would like to code this one up as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can first [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `Series` from `lists`, then create one column with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `tolist()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'created':[['X','Y','Z', 'A'], 
                              ['A','B'],
                              ['nan'],
                              ['C'],
                              ['W','F','X','A'],
                              ['Q']]},
                              index=["2015-02-08","2015-02-15","2015-02-22",
                                     "2015-03-01","2015-03-08","2015-03-15"])

print df
                created
2015-02-08  [X, Y, Z, A]
2015-02-15        [A, B]
2015-02-22         [nan]
2015-03-01           [C]
2015-03-08  [W, F, X, A]
2015-03-15           [Q]
```

```
df = df['created'].apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates()
print df
2015-02-08  0      X
            1      Y
            2      Z
            3      A
2015-02-15  1      B
2015-02-22  0    nan
2015-03-01  0      C
2015-03-08  0      W
            1      F
2015-03-15  0      Q
dtype: object

print df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
2015-02-08    [X, Y, Z, A]
2015-02-15             [B]
2015-02-22           [nan]
2015-03-01             [C]
2015-03-08          [W, F]
2015-03-15             [Q]
dtype: object
```

If you need `DataFrame`:

```
print pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.tolist()), columns=['created'])
                 created
2015-02-08  [X, Y, Z, A]
2015-02-15           [B]
2015-02-22         [nan]
2015-03-01           [C]
2015-03-08        [W, F]
2015-03-15           [Q]
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to create a new DF/series, my values all are arrays, and I already have a series created from:

`companies = users_file2.set_index('Created').Values_Column companies = companies.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='W')).unique()`

Comment: I created Series and DataFrame, because delete duplicated items of arrays is very complicated and with Series/DataFrames it is more easy. Is possible remove duplicates before creating arrays? And store arrays in columns is possible, but for processing very complicated. But if output in arrays is important, I think the best is in the end of processing convert output to arrays.

Comment: so this works: `new_companies_weekly_count = companies[:].apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates()
new_companies_weekly_count = new_companies_weekly_count.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
new_companies_weekly_count`